# Display Vocabulary (VID) From Selected Field

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to print out the selected vocabulary from a content type on a page.  As the previous user did not use views for this layout, I need to find a way to add it.

Here is my code so far.

foreach ( (array)$node->taxonomy as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }?>

Right now, it shows all of the terms that are listed in my taxonomy. Is there a way to narrow this down? to only show selected vid?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for future purposes:

```
<?php
```

$vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
if ($vocabularies) {
  foreach($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
    if ($vocabulary->vid == 1) {
      $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid);
      if ($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
          print $term->name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>

Did the trick.